# Newly shrunk volume causing EC2 instance to fail Instance Status Checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, volume

Recently we realized that one of our instances was much too powerful for our needs. In turn, we decided to minimize the power of the server. For starters, we decided to go with a smaller instance size. That seemed to work fine. We were able to snapshot the production volume, create the smaller instance, attach the production volume, and everything worked fine. Afterwards, we decided to decrease the hard drive space. Here is where things fell apart.

We struggled finding good instructions online for this task specific to EC2 or linux in general. After putting our heads together, we figured out how to successfully clone the existing hard drive onto a smaller drive. Below are the general steps we followed:

1. Create new snapshot of current asset hard drive
2. Create new volume from snapshot
3. Create new asset server and attach new volume
4. Create new smaller volume at 20GB
5. Test new asset server, make sure it works
6. Create new micro instance
7. Stop new asset server and detach volume
8. Stop micro instance
9. Attach 2 drives to micro instance
10. Log into micro instance and create partition on smaller drive
11. Create file system on smaller drive -
12. Confirm big drive is already file system -
13. Mount big drive on server
14. Mount small drive on server
15. sync content rsync -ahHAX   (no slash after target)
16. Unmount drives
17. Stop micro instance
18. Detach drives from micro instance
19. Attach new small drive to original instance
20. Start original instance

Now we constantly get the 1/2 status error when starting the instance. We're unable to SSH into it, view in browser, or connect in any way. Please advise.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks!
Chris